# HealthKit: save samples of type HKCategoryTypeIdentifierAppleStandHour

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I try to get authorization to save samples of type HKCategoryTypeIdentifierAppleStandHour:

```
var healthKitTypesToRead: Set<HKObjectType> = Set<HKObjectType>()
var healthKitTypesToWrite: Set<HKSampleType> = Set<HKSampleType>()
healthKitTypesToWrite.insert(HKSampleType.categoryTypeForIdentifier(HKCategoryTypeIdentifierAppleStandHour)!)
...
healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead) { 
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if let error = error {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            print ("success: \(success), error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        })
    }
}
```

when I'm running this code, I get the exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Authorization to share the following types is disallowed:
HKCategoryTypeIdentifierAppleStandHour'
```

Am I doing something wrong or is Apple really prohibiting writing samples of this type?

Tested with (iOS 9.0 and iOS 9.1) and XCode 7.1

**Edit**
iOS 9.3/watchOS 2.2 adds functionality but not this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps are not permitted to save samples with the `HKCategoryTypeIdentifierAppleStandHour` type.  Apps may only query for existing stand hours already stored in HealthKit by the Apple Watch.